# Retrieveing Multiple lines of text using var query

Tags: javascript, variables

I currently have a JS file which displays a single line know issue entered by a user via a SharePoint list. The div id it displays on the page is 'knowntitle'.

I now have been asked to display further information, so that the user would have another field to fill in on the SharePoint list called Further Details would be a Multiple Lines of Text field.

I wrote the original pages a year ago, and I'm a bit rusty! I've made a start and commented out what I've done so far. Any help on how to proceed would be gratefully received, js below:

```
function getDeviceKnownIssues() {

  //var txtfurtherinfo = "";
  var txtTitleKnown = "<ol>";

  var query = "http://xxx/sites/it/ITInfrastructure/_vti_bin/listdata.svc//Knownissues?$filter=DeviceID eq " + window.DeviceId + "";

  var call = $.ajax({
    url: query,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
    }
  });
  call.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    $.each(data.d.results, function(index, item) {
      var KnownTitle = item.Title;
      //var FurtherInfo = item.Info;
      txtTitleKnown = txtTitleKnown + "<li>" + KnownTitle + "</li>";
    });

    txtTitleKnown = txtTitleKnown + "</ol>";
    //$('furtherinfo').append(txtName);
    $('#knowntitle').append(txtTitleKnown);

  });
  call.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert("Error retrieving data: " + jqXHR.responseText);
  });

}
```

Comment: The original code displays the known issues in an `<ol>` list. How do you want to display the further info? You have to think of the design first, and then try to implement it.

Comment: Just as plain text without an ordered list. So I've already added a cell in the page for the text to be displayed

Comment: Yes, but how do you want to display it? I'm assuming that each known issue may have further info. So do you want to display all further info together in the cell that you added? Or am I wrong and there is only one further info for all the known issues? In this case, it looks like you'll have the same value repeated for all known issues, because you're retrieving it by `item.Info`.

Comment: Yes I want it all to be displayed together.

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the further info together with line breaks `\r\n` and them display them in the cell:

```
$.each(data.d.results, function(index, item) {
  txtTitleKnown += "<li>" + item.Title + "</li>";
  if(item.Info != undefined) {
      txtfurtherinfo += item.Info + "\r\n";
  }
});

txtTitleKnown = txtTitleKnown + "</ol>";
$('#knowntitle').append(txtTitleKnown);
$('#furtherinfo').append(txtfurtherinfo);
```

Comment: Thanks. I've added that but it's not showing up in the cell:

Comment: var call = $.ajax({
            url: query,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
            }       
        });
    call.done(function (data,textStatus, jqXHR){
 $.each(data.d.results, function(index, item) {
        var KnownTitle = item.Title;
        txtTitleKnown = txtTitleKnown + "<li>" + KnownTitle + "</li>";
        txtfurtherinfo += item.Info + "\r\n";
    });

    txtTitleKnown = txtTitleKnown + "</ol>";
    $('furtherinfo').append(txtfurtherinfo);

Comment: Copy and paste my answer instead of modifying your code. You must use `$('#furtherinfo')`, not `$('furtherinfo')` like in your code.

Comment: I added # into $('#furtherinfo) and now it's showing undefined in the cell?

Comment: That means there is no data coming back in `item.Info`. Check you data, we cannot help you with that.

Comment: The odd things is that if I enter six lines of text I get six 'undefineds' am I using the wrong variable?

Comment: That's normal. See my updated answer. You can check to make sure that `item.Info` has data before you add it. In your case, you will see nothing in the cell because you're saying that you're not getting any data back. Fix your data and it will work.

Comment: To answer your question *am I using the wrong variable?*, I don't know if `item.Info` is the correct property or not. You can print out your data using `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));` to see what you're getting. You can post the result in your question if you need help with it.

Comment: Right, so basically I'm not getting the info back from the 'Further details' multiple lines of text field so do I need to rename:

  txtfurtherinfo += item.Info + "\r\n";  to 'item.Further details   ?

Comment: Probably. I don't see your data, so I cannot tell. Like I said, you use `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));` to see how your data is coming back, and use the right field.

Comment: Hi I think I put the console log code in the right place:
call.done(function (data,textStatus, jqXHR){
 $.each(data.d.results, function(index, item) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); 
  txtTitleKnown += "<li>" + item.Title + "</li>";
  if(item.Info != undefined) {
      txtfurtherinfo += item.Info + "\r\n";

Pressed  F12 on Chrome and got:

ProcessKnownIssue":"5","NotificationSent":"No","FurtherDetails":"<div class=\"ExternalClass386B6A8DF1DD4091B84DC82BFC1BE2BF\"><p>Yayayayayayayayayaya</p></div>"

Which seems to suggest that it's capturing the data?

Comment: No, you need to put it before `$.each()`. I don't understand the results the it gave you. There is no `d` or `results` properties, so I don't understand how the `$.each(data.d.results)` is working. Also there are no `Title` and `Info` properties, so I don't understand how you're getting your list. Are you sure you posted all the data from `console.log()`? Move it before `$.each()` and post all the data here. No need for the code, only the data.

Comment: Okay great thanks. I've put the consol.log between jqXHR){     and $.each(data.d.results.

Don't think the results help much: 

Navigated to http://example.com/sites/it/ITInfrastructure/Service%20Catalogue%20Library/Forms/AllItems.aspx
Navigated to

Comment: http://example.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED
Service Catalogue Devices.aspx:837 GET http://example.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED
VM753 sp.ui.rte.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentElement' of null
    at RTE.Canvas.checkCurrentFocus (VM753 sp.ui.rte.js:2)
RTE.Canvas.checkCurrentFocus @ VM753 sp.ui.rte.js:2
setTimeout (async)
RTE.Canvas.setInitialFocus @ VM753 sp.ui.rte.js:2
RTE.Canvas.load @ VM753 sp.ui.rte.js:2
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ VM753 sp.ui.rte.js:2

Comment: VM1066 sp.ui.rte.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentElement' of null
    at RTE.Canvas.checkCurrentFocus (VM1066 sp.ui.rte.js:2)
RTE.Canvas.checkCurrentFocus @ VM1066 sp.ui.rte.js:2
setTimeout (async)
RTE.Canvas.setInitialFocus @ VM1066 sp.ui.rte.js:2
RTE.Canvas.load @ VM1066 sp.ui.rte.js:2
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ VM1066 sp.ui.rte.js:2
Navigated to http://example.com/sites/it/ITInfrastructure/Lists/Knownissues/NewForm.aspx?RootFolder=
Navigated to http://example.com/sites/it/ITInfrastructure/Lists/Knownissues/AllItems.aspx

Comment: Hi @Racil Hilan I've added some more details on this page. I suspect that the reason it's not showing up is because of something on the HTML side: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49508241/var-query-not-returning-required-results